# AndroidのEditTextで編集はさせずフォーカスのみ行える状態にする

Tags: android

AndroidのEditTextで、編集はさせずフォーカスのみ行える状態にすることは可能でしょうか？
タップしてもキーボードを出させない、ということになります。

```
android:editable="false"
android:focusable="false"
```

これが調べた結果ヒットしましたが、これでは完全にフォーカスができなくなってしまいます。
どうすればいいんでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

XMLではうまく働かないようです。

EditTextのインスタンスに

edittext.setKeyListener(null);

とするとうまくいきました。

参考：
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3928711/how-to-make-edittext-not-editable-through-xml-in-android

Comment: フォーカスの際、カーソルを表示できませんか？

Comment: キーボードを表示するのか。表示した場合入力は受け付けるのか。入力は受けるがEditTextに反映させないのか。決まっていることを書いてください。